# Dashboard display two blocks pagination

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have two block views in my Drupal 7 site dashboard: One is a custom module and one is a normal views block. Both are assigned to the dashboard.

The custom module has a table in the block_view hook. It also has a pagination in it. The second one is generated via the Views module, and also has a table with pagination.

When I go to the second page or to any page of the first table, the second table is updated too.

> [image: The first page]

> [image: The second page]

I made the view based table's pagination AJAX based, but I suppose it is not to right way.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: May be useful: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/multiple-blocks-on-single-page-pager-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the ID of one of the pagers. For the Views module is under *Pager setting*, *Field pager ID*.

The description for that field says:

> Unless you're experiencing problems with pagers related to this view, you should leave this at 0. If using multiple pagers on one page you may need to set this number to a higher value so as not to conflict within the ?page= array. Large values will add a lot of commas to your URLs, so avoid if possible.