# Multiple blocks on single page, pager issue

Tags: 7, views, blocks, paging

I have 3 blocks made by views on the front page. Each have 4 of the newest node teasers showing with a pager to see the rest. However, when I click on one of the pager's next button, it will load the next 'page' for all the blocks on the page.

What would be the best way to make it so pressing the next button will only load that specific blocks next page and not the other blocks?

Comment: Will do. I was simply voting the answer I thought was the best. I didn't know I had to accept it with the check mark until I saw your comment. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure each block's pager to have a different pager ID and then they will/should only update the one you clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

You may also test enabling AJAX and the different views should page individually.